# non-template std::reference_wrapper assignment operator and template constructor

Tags: c++, templates, assignment-operator, c++20, reference-wrapper

In the C++ 20 Standard the constructor of the class template `std::reference_wrapper` is a template.

```
template<class U>
constexpr reference_wrapper(U&&) noexcept(see below );
```

while the assignment operator is not a template

```
constexpr reference_wrapper& operator=(const reference_wrapper& x) noexcept;
```

What is the reason that this difference (template and non-template) between these special member functions exists?

On the other hand, I tried the following progarm using Visual C++ 2019.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    void f() const { std::cout << "A::f()\n"; }
    virtual void g() const { std::cout << "A::g()\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
    void f() const { std::cout << "B::f()\n"; }
    void g() const override { std::cout << "B::g()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    std::reference_wrapper<A> r( b );

    r.get().f();
    r.get().g();


    r = std::reference_wrapper<B>( b );
}
```

and the compiler did not issue an error message relative to the assignment operator.

Is it a bug of the compiler or have I missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `std::reference_wrapper<T>` had a single constructor accepting `T&`, then it would lead to bugs like `std::reference_wrapper<const T>` being able to bind to temporaries of type `T`. So, originally there were two constructors (other than the copy constructor): one taking `T&`, and another taking `T&&`, which was defined as deleted, ensuring that a compile error would occur.

However, it was pointed out that this is not really what we want: it would be better if `std::reference_wrapper<T>` would have no constructor at all that accepts an rvalue of type `T`, as opposed to a deleted constructor. This is [LWG 2993](https://wg21.link/lwg2993). (You'll notice that this issue is mentioned at the bottom of the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper).) Thus, the constructor was changed to a template that is SFINAE-disabled as appropriate.

Once these issues are solved for the constructor, the assignment operator only needs to have a single overload taking `reference_wrapper`. The conversion issues will be handled by the constructor logic when the compiler forms the implicit conversion sequence.

Comment: But the standard does not allow  accepting by the constructor an object of the type std::reference_wrapper.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow there is a copy constructor, is there not?

Comment: The copy constructor is also a non-template constructor.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes, there is a copy constructor and a template converting constructor, but I don't understand where you're going with this.